# Problems after updating Xcode to 4.6 and iOS to 6.1

Tags: app-store, code-signing, provisioning, xcode4.6, ios6.1

I hope somebody can help me. I had just finished my app and ready to upload it to the APP Store when I updated XCode to 4.6 and the iOS on my iPhone to 6.1. Now I can't even test the APP in my own device without getting the following error:

```
error: failed to launch '/Users/Drausio/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Surf+-   hifxllpzxwzhrqgnmsjhoikiuomi/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Surf+.app/Surf+' 
-- No such file or directory (/Users/Drausio/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Surf+-hifxllpzxwzhrqgnmsjhoikiuomi/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Surf+.app/Surf+)
```

Besides, I'm having all sorts of code signing errors when I try to upload the app. Errors like:

```
Application failed code sign verification. The signature was invalid, contains disallowed entitlements, or it was not signed with an iPhone Distribution Certificate.

Unable to extract codesining entitlements from your application. Please make sure Surf+ is a valid Mach executable that's properly signed.
```

I checked and rechecked every certificate and provisioning profile. Developer and distribution, but I ran out of ideas.

Thanks in advance for ideas!!

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question, apparently XCode didn't like the name of my app. I changed it to Surf-.app and everything happened as magic.